# Why -nan(ind) problem is happened in my code

Tags: c, nan

```
double power_func(double a, int b, double c) {
    if (b == 0)
        return 1.0;
    else if (b == 1)
        return a;
    else 
        a *= c;
        
    power_func(a, b - 1, c);
}
```

if i call this function with the value of b, 0 or 1, it is working but if i give b value not those 0 or 1, it is printed '-nan(ind)'. Please tell me why it is happening.

Comment: The function is not always returning any value, as the compiler will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `return` before `power_func(a, b - 1, c);`

Comment: @Hughes I'm glad I could help :) If no further assistance is needed, please mark my answer as accepted, so that other people saw, that this question is answered and could skip it to assist others :)